# Whem i'm Creating a File With name of "Anonymous.dart" it gives me error that you can't create a file with this name?

Tags: file, dart, visual-studio-code, filenames

I am Working in Vscode since 2020 and i never seen this type of errror that's telling me that "The name `Anonymous.dart` is not valid as a file or folder name.Please choose a different name."

**Note:-After trying for few times it's now working and it created the file with name "Anonymous.dart".**

Here is Image:-

[image]

I want to curious to know the Reason Behind This

Thanks In Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style) recommends using `lowercase_with_underscores` file names.

There is no deeper reason behind it. It works and is safe whereas uppercase letters or spaces might cause trouble on some operating systems. More on this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7273448/669294

Answer (score 0):

You should type as manually instead of copy paste. Or at least paste and remove (.ts) then type. It will accept .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).