# Is there a standard for storing generated files in a JavaScript project?

Tags: javascript, project-layout

When creating a project JavaScript project my standard file layout looks like this:

```
project-name/
 |- bower_components/
 |- node_modules/
 |- src/
 |- tests/
 |- .csslintrc
 |- .jshintrc
 |- .htmlhintrc
 |- bower.json
 |- Gruntfile.js
 `- package.json
```

`node_modules` and `bower_components` are standard. I've also noticed that `src` or `www` are some kind of standard for source files and `spec`, `specs`, `test` or `tests` are mostly used for tests. `dist` is really common for putting releasable files.

However, I also often get generated files such as `css` generated from my `less` files. Those files belong in the `dist` folder when releasing, but is there some kind of standard for where to put those files when testing locally on a webserver? tend to use `bower_components` because it is already hosted on the local webserver, but it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 0):

> 3.3. CSS files MUST have the file extension .css and SHOULD be stored in the relevant includes directory in the site structure, usually
>   /style/.

Source: http://www.bbc.co.uk/guidelines/futuremedia/technical/css.shtml

> /assets/

and

> /resources/

are other common places for css files
See for example https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/issues/1121

See also the similar question [Naming convention for assets (images, css, js)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2071687/naming-convention-for-assets-images-css-js)

All-in-all it is up to you, but make sure it is consistent, and logical.